# Sandbox Account Dashboard for Square's E-Commerce API?

Tags: square-connect

I am working on an integration using Square's E-Commerce API. Sandbox account is set up and I've been able to complete test transactions. I can review transactions via the API and see all the appropriate entries, but is there a Dashboard available to view the sandbox transactions? If I log in to my Square account, there are no transactions visible, but I am assuming that it only shows "live" transactions. I would like to ultimately see what the my client will see in their Square dashboard (they will be using a Square POS in-store).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our dashboard and Register app do not currently expose sandbox data. The only way to retrieve this data is by using our Connect v2 REST APIs.

I'll pass this use case along as a feature request.